# Changing state/props of root component with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have my root component that renders something like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={this.state.messages}>
    <Router>
      <App>
        // routes
      </App>
    </Router>
  </IntlProvider>
</Provider>
```

I'm getting `this.state.messages` dynamically (async, Redux action + reducer) from the back-end as an object. I'm storing it in Redux store. How do I pass the Redux store `messages` to `this.state.messages` (`props` would do as well).

Plot twist: I CAN'T USE react-redux `connect` with this component, because it's the root component and it's not within `<Provider>` (it introduces it), so, doing this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    messages: state.messages
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RootComponent);
```

Ends in:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(RootComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(RootComponent)".
```

Is there a way of accessing Redux store in a different, sane manner? I was thinking about store.getState() but it accepts no arguments and mapping over all the state items seems like an overkill when I want to get just one of them. Or maybe I do something wrong and after all `connect` should work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a connected react component that will wrap the IntlProvider, and pass messages to it.

Sample code (haven't tested):

```
const ConnectedIntlProvider = ({ children, ...props }) => ( // the props contain the messages and the locale
  <IntlProvider locale="en" { ...props }>
  { children }
  </IntlProvider>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  messages: state.messages
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedIntlProvider);
```

Usages:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <ConnectedIntlProvider locale="en">
    <Router>
      <App>
        // routes
      </App>
    </Router>
  </ConnectedIntlProvider>
</Provider>
```