# How to make translation runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm doing a simple **runtime** translation.
When I hit the locale switcher, nothing happened. If i refresh the page, the **title** has changed. So, it's not **runtime** translation.

Translation image:
[image]

Here my code:

Admin:

```
import { en } from './languages/English';
import { fr } from './languages/French';
const messages = {
 en,
 fr
}
<Admin ... 
  locale={localStorage.getItem('language') ? localStorage.getItem('language') : 'en'}
  messages={messages}
>
 ....
</Admin>
```

Locale Switcher:

```
switchToFrench = () => this.props.changeLocale('fr');
switchToEnglish = () => this.props.changeLocale('en');
switchLanguage(language) {
    localStorage.setItem('language', language);
    this.props.changeLocale(language);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Language</div>
            <button label="en" onClick={() => this.switchLanguage('en')}>English</button>
            <button label="fr" onClick={() => this.switchLanguage('fr')}>French</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

English/French file:

```
export const en = {
 name: 'English',
 locale: 'en',
 user: {
    no: 'No',
    name: 'Name',
    username: 'User Name',
    email: 'Email',
 }
}
export const fr = {
 name: 'French',
 locale: 'fr',
 user: {
    no: 'No',
    name: 'Nom',
    username: 'Nom d\'utilisateur',
    email: 'Email',
 }
}
```

UserList:

```
class UserList extends Component {
render() {
    const { translate } = this.props;
    return(
        <div>
            <LocaleSwitcher />
            <List title="All users" {...this.props}>
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id" label={translate('user.no')}/>
                    <TextField source="name" label={translate('user.name')}/>
                    <TextField source="username" label={translate('user.username')}/>
                    <EmailField source="email" label={translate('user.email')}/>
                </Datagrid>
            </List>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default translate(UserList);
```

I'm using all default components from aor.
Please show me the way to make a runtime translation.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the LocaleSwitcher component under the Admin component and in a callBack function do this.forceUpdate(). This will re-render the admin component and the right locale will come from the local storage. like this:

```
<Admin ... 
   locale={localStorage.getItem('language') ? 
   localStorage.getItem('language') 
   : 'en'}
   messages={messages}
>
    <LocaleSwitcher onChange={() => this.forceUpdate()}/>
</Admin>
```

If you use redux it's better to use the store like in this answer:
[Changing state/props of root component with Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495723/changing-state-props-of-root-component-with-redux/47495814#47495814)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

In this document [link](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Translation.html)

The runtime translation is possible. And I'm trying to create another component(not aor component). It's working well.
I expected that using redux for it. forceUpdate function is not good for me.

Comment: @LinhTrần Did you find a solution?

Comment: Daniel, when I add `<LocaleSwitcher/>` under the `<Admin>` I receive error like this: 
```Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `AdminRoutes`.
    in Route (created by AdminRoutes)
    in AdminRoutes (created by Connect(AdminRoutes))```

Comment: Ilioor, it doesn't seems connected to the addition of<LocaleSwitcher/>. Check if in AdminRoutes there is a map function that build the routes and not gives to each route a key.

Comment: @llioor Not actually yet. Right now, I created a new page, and name it "Configuration"(aor guild). When I change the language, move to other page. It's working but not be runtime. I think it's ok for me now.

Answer (score 1):

AOR provides locale change actions to do so (here is [a working example on the demo](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest-demo/#/configuration)):

[image: locale switcher in action]

The source code is available on github: [marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/a67978a6f69e7dfbb937f66baaa49e787e5853ec/src/configuration/Configuration.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Card, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { translate, changeLocale as changeLocaleAction, ViewTitle } from 'admin-on-rest';

const Configuration = ({ locale, changeLocale, translate }) => (
    <Card>
        <ViewTitle title={translate('pos.configuration')} />
        <CardText>
            <div style={styles.label}>{translate('pos.language')}</div>
            <RaisedButton
                label="en"
                primary={locale === 'en'}
                onClick={() => changeLocale('en')}
            />
            <RaisedButton
                label="fr"
                primary={locale === 'fr'}
                onClick={() => changeLocale('fr')}
            />
        </CardText>
    </Card>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    locale: state.locale,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    changeLocale: changeLocaleAction,
})(translate(Configuration));
```

Comment: I know. It seems to be not runtime action. Example, when I put the language part on navigation bar(French and English). Then, change locale and some default component hasn't changed(**Datagrid, List, Texfield**).

Comment: @LinhTrần Thank you for you comment! It helped me understand my issue... but still I didn't find the solution to update all Admin component after changeLocale(). Did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm not going to change the whole project to use [Custom App](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html) just for switching locales I end up with this solution.

I'm using `SelectField` with `onChange={this.switchToLocale}` because of it I receive `(event, index, value)`. Feel free to use the example from the Docs. The important part is the `reload()` function.

```
switchToLocale = (event, index, value) => {
    localStorage.setItem('locale', value);
    this.props.changeLocale(value);
    window.location.reload();
};
```

I'm not happy with it but I don't think the admin is going to change his locale every minute.

Comment: yes. you're right. But when i say it's **runtime**. I mean i don't want to reload page.

Comment: Yes yes I got it, in order to use it as *WE* want we need to implement a custom app... Do you agree with it? Because of it I started with "Because I'm not going to change the whole project to use Custom App". If you find a good solution please share it for the community. Thanks a lot!